# Is the subject-mismatch allowed in "Après s’être amusée, il lui arrive de ..."?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-impersonnels

I just said in conversation:

> Ta fille est partie jouer. Après **s’être amusée**, **il lui arrive** de nous ramener quelque chose d'intéressant.

The omitted subject of the "après" subordinate clause is "elle", whereas the main clause has a placeholder subject "il", and therein lies the subject-mismatch.

Granted, I used "lui" as an indirect object in the main clause, but it is not the subject. I wonder if this sentence construction is grammatical?

Comment: I guess only a member of académie française could bother you with this construction...

Comment: yes definitely. I do not know if it is correct or not by académie's standards, it might even be.

Comment: @QuentinRuyant If I'd had a bit more time to think, I would've used "elle" as the subject: "Après s’être amusée, ***elle*** nous ramène souvent ...". But as it was a spontaneous speech, I guess I sort of intuitively settled for using "lui" to at least place a replacement for "elle".

Comment: or "il arrive qu'elle nous ramène..." or "après qu'elle se soit amusée" but that's really not important I think.

Answer (score 4):

Here in "il lui arrive" *il* does not refer to *fille*, it's the subject
of impersonal use of verb *arriver* (il arrive que), like in "il faut que",
"il se trouve que..." etc.

Comment: C'est justement le problème soulevé par la question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sentence using a similar structure.

> Après s’être préparée, un vilain coup de vent lui retarda son projet de navigation de plusieurs heures.

The active subject of the first clause was her, whoever she is. She appears again as “lui”, substituted for “elle”, in the second clause, as the victim of a “vilain coup de vent” that delays her departure.

The sequence of events is clear *(AFTER she got ready came an event that prevented her from departing immediately)*.

The status of the different actors and the relation between the consequences of their actions is also clear *(BECAUSE the wind got worse than it was, she had to postpone her travel, though she was otherwise ready to go)*.

Everything is so clear that it would be hard to call it ungrammatical. Of course we could reorganize the sentence, but it is neither necessary nor would it make it a lot less ambiguous.

---

Here is another such sentence where the subject of the first clause *(JE)* is not even present in the second clause. However, it does remain clear, and it is from the highest authority of the French language.

> Je n’irai point là [QUE](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie4/que) tout ne soit prêt.  –*Dictionnaire de l’Académie, 4e édition*

In this case again, the meaning is clear: *JE* will not be found *THERE* prior to *“everything being ready”*.

Here are other examples from worthy authors:

> Une heure après qu’**Albertine** était couchée, **j**’allai jusqu’à son lit.  –Marcel PROUST, *À la recherche du temps perdu*
>
> **La pluie** avait cessé que **nous** allions encore à toute vitesse –Georges DUHAMEL, *Les hommes abandonnés*

---

Back to the original sentence in the question:

> Ta fille est partie jouer. Après s’être amusée, il lui arrive de nous ramener quelque chose d’intéressant.

The sequence of events is clear *(AFTER she’s done playing, SHE sometimes bring something interesting back)*.

*SHE* is also present in the second clause, though as a secondary actor, and as the perhaps unintuitive *LUI*.

So the main subject of the first clause is still less of an abstraction in the second clause than it is in the Academy example.

The sentence could also easily be reorganized, though it would add very little clarity to this already correctly formed statement:

> Après s’être amusée, *ELLE* nous ramène parfois quelque chose d’intéressant.

---

**Conclusion:** the sentence is correct. Not very many people will complain about it, because it is clear, similar examples are attested by good writers and by the Academy, and it achieves its main intent of communicating what it has to communicate.

Answer (score 1):

I think that "il" actually replaces the infinitive subordinate clause:

*"Nous ramener quelque chose lui arrive" is the idea behind the sentence.

Your sentence is just fine.

Comment: Je pense aussi que la phrase est correcte (en fait, il m'a fallu réfléchir pour voir le problème) mais votre argument est peu convaincant. Précisément, si on remplace comme vous faîtes "Après s'être amusée,
nous ramener quelque chose lui arrive", la phrase est beaucoup moins claire que l'originale.

Comment: je ne proposais pas cela comme une alternative mais comme une phrase explicative, d'où mon * pour signaler que la phrase est incorrecte. je voulais juste insister sur le fonctionnement profond de la phrase

Comment: Ce que je veux dire c'est que *précisément d'après ce fonctionnement profond*, la phrase semble ne pas devoir être correcte (en tout cas pas plus correcte qu'avant). Le problème de fond est que le sujet d'*arriver* est *quelque chose* et non *elle* et donc qu'il y a un changement de sujet entre les deux propositions.
Votre "réponse" ne répond pas à ce problème.